# grpc kotlin plugin is not generating dsl code

Tags: kotlin, microservices, grpc, protobuf-java, kotlin-dsl

I have an existing project which is using gradle with kotlin DSL. I have setup protobuf code auto-generation with gradle build.

Kotlin grpc code is generated and I am able to implement my backend using flows and coroutines.

But the kotlin DSL code is not getting generated. So I am currently left with usage of verbose boilerplate driven builder pattern for creating my objects.

Below is my protobuf plugin setup.

```
protobuf {

//    generatedFilesBaseDir = "generated-sources"
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3"
    }
    plugins {
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.39.0"
        }

        id("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.2.0:jdk7@jar"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach {
            it.plugins {
                id("grpc") {}
                id("grpckt") {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching the Internet for an answer, I have found one from [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/518)

Looks like grpc implementers have changed the way the plugin is configured.
So answering my own question so it might save some time for the next developer.

```
protobuf {

    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3"
    }
    plugins {
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.39.0"
        }

        id("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.2.0:jdk7@jar"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach {
            it.plugins {
                id("grpc") {}
                id("grpckt") {}
            }

            it.builtins {
                id("kotlin")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key is adding this block. Then my protobuf messages' have kotlin DSL functions generated.

```
            it.builtins {
                id("kotlin")
            }
```

After configuring Kotlin DSL generation, compilation was failing. Then I had to add **protobuf-kotlin** dependency.

```
implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.19.1")
```